# Table name as "type" field in table

Tags: sql, syntax

This was kind of difficult to search for because the words involved are kind of generic in the field of relational databases, so if this is duplicate, please point me in the right direction.

Say I have a 'hotspot' table. Say a hotspot could appear in any number of link tables. I don't want to make unnecessary queries in all the link tables, I want to specify a 'hotspot' type so I could first get my result and only find relations for a specific type.

Is it bad practice to make a 'link_type' column that references the real name of a link table? For instance say I have these link tables:

```
table link_hotspot_collectable
table link_hotspot_minigame
table link_hotspot_factoid
```

Where the following tables are unique tables with varying quantities/types of data

```
table collectable
table minigame
table factoid
```

Then a possible value for the column 'link_type' would be 'collectable' or 'minigame' (or I suppose I could use the whole link table name 'link_hotspot_factoid'

Is this a good approach? Is there a more efficient or better schema to form easier/faster queries?

The purpose is to generalize "hotspots" (goemetric coordinates in a pixel mapped space) with any other set of actions/collectibles/games. the games table would be drastically different than the schema of the collectibles table.

Comment: are all the "link tables" the same format? if so you should consider just having one table with a property field instead of 3 diferent tables and then you can seutup views for each type

Comment: I once did this kind of a thing when I had to custom implement a db synchronization where a map of data btween databases were stored. So my answer is it depends. If it's relevant for you then it is ok, but to know it you have to tell us what are u intending to do. But I recommend you to sore enum values as link_type rather than fully qualified names

Comment: I suppose the link tables would be all the same format, they're just FK stores linking a hotspot to a row in another table of varying type. So, then my query would be FROM linktable WHERE hotspot_id is XXX and then I'd have all the links then i would have a property that indicates what table the next query should be on, such as TABLE collectable. I guess that would work.

Comment: Is there something better than link tables I should be using to form these types of relational models?

Comment: *‘a hotspot could appear in any number of link tables’* – you mean, in *more than one* link table? What purpose would specifying a type serve then?

Comment: Also, how many distinct types are there that can be linked to `hotspot`? Is that number fixed? If so and if not many, you could consider a single link table with a separate link column per type. (Or you could even incorporate them in `hotspot` if a hotspot can be linked to no more than one entity of the same type.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the schema below (putting it in generic example so I can describe it in an easier way):

```
 ___________     _________     _____
|Cars       |   |Planes   |   |Parts|
-------------   -----------   -------
|-Id        |   |-Id      |   |-Id  |
|-RideHeight|   |-Wingspan|   |-Name|
-------------   -----------   -------
 ___________     ___________
|Plane_Parts|   |Car_Parts  |
-------------   -------------
|-PlaneId   |   |-CarId     |
|-PartId    |   |-PartId    |
-------------   -------------
```

What I think you're asking is if you could change `Parts` to include a type discriminator, would it make querying faster/easier:

```
 ______
|Parts |
--------
|-Id   |
|-Name |
|-Type | (Plane, Car, etc.)
 ------
```

In this new schema, you would hope to do something like this: "I have a part id, find the part, then if it's a plane I'll query for the plane info instead of even looking at cars". Consider the consequences:

- You've just duplicated information in the database. In the original model, the join tables already declare what types of parts join to which type of vehicle. You're now adding another column that must be manually set and provides the same information in an unchecked way. This could easily get out of sync and give you a headache that can easily be avoided.
- You've removed the ability to have one part apply to both a plane or a car. The original schema could have a radio that is used in a plane or a car, but adding a type field eliminates this possibility. This may never be the case for your schema, but it adds confusion for anyone that is trying to understand your schema. Unfortunately, the constraint: "each part can only join to records in the `Cars` table ***or*** records in the `Planes` table" isn't possible afaik, but a specified type column doesn't guarantee that either.
- It was never that difficult/slow to get the results you're after anyway. A join on all the relevant tables would be just as clear to anyone familiar with SQL as a switch statement that decides what the second part of the query should be. It would actually probably be slower the way you described since you have to pull down a whole collection, then run another query to get the results you're looking for. SQL server will likely just do it on the fly and build the necessary results based on existing indexes.

Hopefully this is similar to what you're describing. If it is, I don't see any advantage to adding a `Type` field that is worth the difficulties of managing a type column. If this is not what you're describing, let me know and I can fix this response.

Comment: I guess " Unfortunately, the constraint: "each part can only join to records in the Cars table or records in the Planes table" isn't possible afaik, but a specified type column doesn't guarantee that either." Could only happen during validation really =)